# Moving a UIWebView on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS application and I'm having trouble with the navigation. I'm new to xCode and my assumption is that most dynamic content will be handled through WebViews. My plan is to have 4 WebViews. One with the dynamic content and the other three for options.

My terrible Diagram:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYoar.png

The center view with the content created via JavaScript will be dragged around. My example is something like the Youtube app where you drag to the side for options.

The Final product would be something like this, but include the usual iOS overscroll and bounce.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v325L.gif

As of right now I have loaded the center web view with my local html. I'm a bit lost as to where to go from here. From here I need help with dragging the view and adding the easing. I realize it's a big question, but if someone could at least point me in the correct direction, then it would be much appreciated.

However, if someone is looking at this and thinks I'm going in the wrong direction for developing structure, then please tell me.

Thanks Guys

Comment: "Terrible" diagram? Have you seen what most diagrams look like?

Comment: Your assumption is not valid at all. Web views should only be used to show HTML content and a few other file types (such as PDF or Word documents, for example). Otherwise your views should be written with native code using view controllers and other appropriate classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *could* do this with web views, there's really no need to do so. Web views are well suited for displaying mixed-media styled text or arbitrary websites. However, they're actually quite a bit *more* difficult to work with for doing interactive touch-and-drag kinds of interactions. You can do it, and if you're an expert in Javascript, feel free to start there and see how things go. But if not, there's no need to start with that.

Bonus: if you use native views instead of web views, you get most of the animations and "rubber-banding" for free.

If I were doing this, I'd create a view controller. When it loads its view, I'd add a subview that fills the bounds of its superview. Then add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` using the `-[UIView addGestureRecognizer:]` method. When the user starts panning, check which direction they're moving, and add the appropriate options subview behind the front view. Then modify the `center` property of the front view.

Based on the wording of your question, I suspect this level of detail may not be enough to get you where you're trying to go. There are probably four or five more steps along the way that you should take first. I'd suggest this course of action:

1. Figure out how to display simple content without a web view. Text, etc.
2. Figure out how to respond to button presses, etc., outside of a web view.
3. Figure out how to use a gesture recognizer to make a red box follow your finger.
4. Figure out how to dynamically add views to an existing hierarchy. (e.g. Add a new red box every time you touch the screen.)
5. Figure out how to make a view *animate* to the position of your touch. (Search the documentation for "UIView animation".)

Along the way, feel free to ask questions, detailing what you've tried. Once you've done some of this stuff, I think some of the underlying principles start to click. At that point, you may be ready to start on this triple-optioned view.

I hope this is helpful. It sounds like you've got an idea of what you want, and just aren't sure how to get there. Hopefully, these can be some stepping stones to get you there.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, I wish I could vote up

Comment: I think I may still have to use the WebView, because the main view that moves is styled fairly extensively with CSS and I don't really see any options to style it well enough. Any options?

Comment: If you have to use CSS, then yes, you'll have to use a web view. But depending on what kind of styling you are doing, you can often do it without. See, for example, `NSAttributedString`. It's just hard to say exactly what you need without seeing more context.

Comment: I think I may have that portion sorted out, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the dragging to snap to the menus? Would pagecontrol carry over somehow?